# Input [value] changing its value to undefined when typing inside

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am not that experienced with javascript and when I loop through my array of hobbies I wanna populate a FormArray like this:

```
<div formArrayName="hobbies">
    <h4>Add a hobby</h4>
<button (click)="onAddHobby()">
  add
</button>
<div *ngFor="let hobbyControl of profileForm.get('hobbies').controls; let i = index">
  <input [value]="hobbyControl.value?.name" [formControlName]="i"/>
</div>
```

Problem is whenever I type in the input the text becomes undefined. When I printed in the console to see what happens I get my object hobby into a string because of the [value] (I think)

```
hobbies: Array(4)
0: "undefinedff"
1: {name: "Reading"}
2: {name: "Workout"}
3: {name: "Pixel Art"}
```

This leads to a further problem when I am trying to submit the form back, because is not an array of objects anymore.

```
onChanges() {
this.profileForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  this.data.hobbies = val.hobbies;
});
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

I am not sure this equality thing is the best approach, but its the best I came with for now, I am just playing around for now with reactive forms to understand them better.

`this.data` is a material pop-up that will pass the data to the other component that displays whats submitted in the form.

Code below is initializing the form, just for reference:

```
 this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
     // stuff
  }),
     // stuff
  }),
  'hobbies': new FormArray([]),
});

this.data.hobbies.forEach(hobby => {
  (<FormArray>this.profileForm.get('hobbies'))
    .push(new FormControl(hobby));
});
```

And of course I am adding new FormControls in case I need to add more hobbies and they are strings too of course.

Lots of things said. The question is how do I keep my object an object at the end? The object hobbies might grow with more properties, I kept it simple for now to understand a few things.

Thank you

Comment: create a stackblitz example that would help to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using reactive form we should not use value attribute to set value of form control.Since hobbies is array of object we have to create array of FormGroup instead of formControl

**Change as follows**

```
this.data.hobbies.forEach(hobby => {
  (<FormArray>this.profileForm.get('hobbies'))
    .push(new FormGroup({name:new FormControl(hobby.name)}));
});
```

In template change like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let hobbyControl of profileForm.get('hobbies').controls; let i = index">
   <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
      <input  formControlName="name"/>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: When I googled about the issue I came across to this ```[formGroupName]="i"``` but didn't occur to me how to use it in my case, had to ask the question since I knew value is wrong and there must be an elegant way like in your answer. Thank you